# Read a story about 35 yrs ago about an ocean planet that had no land mass (NOT Waterworld)

Tags: story-identification

The boats had special fins on the bottom to help ride out a huge wave that came with regularity. There was a seal-type animal that was infested with a growth of colored fibers that they called “wires”. It was contagious.

Comment: Can you remember anything else about this? What was the plot of the story? Was this a book, short story, series, etc.? If you want to add anything please [edit] those details in.

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is Jack Vance's _[The Blue World](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Blue_World)_ which grew out of a short story "The Kragen".

Comment: Note this doesn't seem to be any of the obvious ocean planets (e.g. Vance's *The Blue World* or Foster's *Cachalot*).

Comment: I don't think this is it but "A Door Into Ocean" by Joan Slonczewski has a mostly ocean-based moon where people live on rafts and there's a regular wave-like phenomenon that crosses the world that the rafts have to be prepared for.  I don't remember anything about this 'wire' disease but there are other books set on the same world I believe.